# How to use modules with Zend_Application?

Tags: zend-framework, module

I'm creating new application using zend framework with several modules. 
Can you please advice me, how to set Zend_Application config file, which includes modules usage?

I was trying to search in ZF manual but there's not relevant information.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put on your application.ini the following line:

```
resources.modules[] =
```

That will load the module resource bootstrap, then use Zend Tool to create the module:

```
zf create module admin
```

And begin working on your modules.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I found also this tutorial, if somebody is searching for more information:

http://akrabat.com/2009/07/08/bootstrapping-modules-in-zf-1-8/